# ScalaCheck selection without replacement

Tags: specs2, scalacheck

How can I write a `Gen[A]` using ScalaCheck that never returns the same object twice?

```
Gen.oneOf(a,b,c)
```

can select the same object repeatedly, so that doesn't work.

I'm writing a mutable specification in specs2, and the reason I want to do this is because the behaviour of the system under test should be to only allow each object to be "used" once, in a certain sense.

**EDIT**: By "the same" I mean the same according to `==`, and the objects are actually strings, so I can't just create the same string each time.

Comment: Do you really need a generator for that? Is it important that the order in which the elements are selected is random?

Comment: @Eric Yes, because otherwise some code paths might not be exercised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking, but there is a generator combinator called `Gen.wrap` that evaluates its argument each time the generator itself is evaluated. That way, you can force creation of new objects. See the example below (note that you can skip the use of `Gen.value` and instead rely on implicit conversion `A => Gen[A]` if you want):

```
scala> import org.scalacheck._
import org.scalacheck._

scala> class A
defined class A

scala> val g1: Gen[A] = Gen.value(new A)
g1: org.scalacheck.Gen[A] = Gen()

scala> g1.sample.get
res0: A = A@45243a0f

scala> g1.sample.get
res1: A = A@45243a0f

scala> val g2: Gen[A] = Gen.wrap(Gen.value(new A))
g2: org.scalacheck.Gen[A] = Gen()

scala> g2.sample.get
res2: A = A@331d4d66

scala> g2.sample.get
res3: A = A@728aed09
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see how this would be useful, but that's not quite what I want - see the update to my question.

Comment: Ah, now I see - I can use it in combination with _any_ generator, so I can write `Gen.wrap(Gen.oneOf(myCollection))` and then remove items from `myCollection` before or after they have been used.